# Cordova calendar plugin for Windows Phone 8

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am looking for a cordova plugin to add events to Windows Phone 8 calendar. There is no plugin on cordova plugin registry. My workaround was to write native plugin-

```
public void addCalendarEvents(String str)
        {
            string[] calendarValues = str.Split('|');           

            SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();

            int appointmentYear = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[3]);
            int appointmentMonth = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[4]);
            int appointmentDate = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[5]);
            float appointmentTime = float.Parse(calendarValues[6]);

            DateTime scheduleApptDateStart = (new DateTime(appointmentYear, appointmentMonth, appointmentDate, 7, 0, 0)).AddHours(appointmentTime);
            DateTime scheduleApptDateEnd = (new DateTime(appointmentYear, appointmentMonth, appointmentDate, 7, 30, 0)).AddHours(appointmentTime);
            saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = scheduleApptDateStart;
            saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = scheduleApptDateEnd;
            saveAppointmentTask.Subject = calendarValues[1];
            saveAppointmentTask.Location = calendarValues[2];
            saveAppointmentTask.Details = "";
            saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
            saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
            saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.Busy;
            saveAppointmentTask.Show();
        }
```

and call it using

```
 var inputCalendarString = notes + '|' + title + '|' + location + '|' + appointmentDate.getFullYear() + '|' + (appointmentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '|' + appointmentDate.getDate() + '|' + '1.0' + '|' + ' ';
                cordova.exec(null, null, "AddCalendarEvents", "addCalendarEvents", inputCalendarString);
```

It works for one event but if I have loop of events its not working. Its not going in cordova success callback. If anybody wrote such plugin, it would be of really great help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new cs file in plugins directory named AddCalendarEvents.cs and add following code-

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.Commands;
using WPCordovaClassLib.Cordova.JSON;

namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands {
    public class AddCalendarEvents: BaseCommand {
        public void addCalendarEvents(String str) {
            string[] calendarValues = str.Split('|');

            SaveAppointmentTask saveAppointmentTask = new SaveAppointmentTask();

            int appointmentYear = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[3]);
            int appointmentMonth = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[4]);
            int appointmentDate = Int32.Parse(calendarValues[5]);
            float appointmentTime = float.Parse(calendarValues[6]);

            DateTime scheduleApptDateStart = (new DateTime(appointmentYear, appointmentMonth, appointmentDate, 7, 0, 0)).AddHours(appointmentTime);
            DateTime scheduleApptDateEnd = (new DateTime(appointmentYear, appointmentMonth, appointmentDate, 7, 30, 0)).AddHours(appointmentTime);
            saveAppointmentTask.StartTime = scheduleApptDateStart;
            saveAppointmentTask.EndTime = scheduleApptDateEnd;
            saveAppointmentTask.Subject = calendarValues[1];
            saveAppointmentTask.Location = calendarValues[2];
            saveAppointmentTask.Details = "";
            saveAppointmentTask.IsAllDayEvent = false;
            saveAppointmentTask.Reminder = Reminder.FifteenMinutes;
            saveAppointmentTask.AppointmentStatus = Microsoft.Phone.UserData.AppointmentStatus.Busy;
            saveAppointmentTask.Show();
        }

        public void getCalendarEventData(String str) {
            ButtonAppointments_Click();
        }

        private void ButtonAppointments_Click() {
            Appointments appts = new Appointments();

            //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
            appts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler < AppointmentsSearchEventArgs > (Appointments_SearchCompleted);

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime end = start.AddDays(7);
            int max = 20;

            //Start the asynchronous search.
            appts.SearchAsync(start, end, max, "Appointments Test #1");
        }

        void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e) {
            //Do something with the results.
            //MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
            try {
                e.Results.ToList();
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            } catch (System.Exception) {}

        }
    }
}
```

Refer plugin in config.xml-

```
<feature name="AddCalendarEvents">
        <param name="wp-package" value="AddCalendarEvents" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
```

You can call it using

```
var inputCalendarString = notes + '|' + title + '|' + location + '|' + appointmentDate.getFullYear() + '|' + (appointmentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '|' + appointmentDate.getDate() + '|' + '1.0' + '|' + ' ';
cordova.exec(null, null, "AddCalendarEvents", "addCalendarEvents", inputCalendarString);
```

It works for one event but if you have loop of events it will not work. To support multiple events, you can maintain Localstorage flag & data with current index of events data. Use resume callback to add rest of the events using custom appointment plugin that you wrote. Each time your app resumes you increment index and add events data from next index.

```
document.addEventListener('resume', this.resumeApp, false)
resumeApp: function () {
if (localStorage.getItem('updatecalendar') == 'false') {
syncUpdatedCalendarWP8();
      }
}
```

[Reference](https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/cordova-calendar-plugin-for-windows-phone-8/)

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get this working. Could you please help me out? Done all like you said in this post. Seems like every time I rebuild with phonegap, the config.xml in the wp8 directory clears the feature node I added for this plugin. Also, I have noticed that all other plugins have a directory dedicated to them. Do I have to create a directory for this plugin inside of the plugins directory or just put it in the root? Lastly, which plugins directory do I put the plugin in? The wp8 specific one or the plugins directory in the root of the phonegap project?

Comment: Could you perhaps give me a github link to your plugin? I would very much appreciate it :)

Comment: Can you try from here-https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/cordova-calendar-plugin-for-windows-phone-8/ Will need some time to upload it to Github.

Comment: Hi, I have created a plugin with the code you have provided but for an unknown reason it does not work :( Could you please have a look and maybe fix what I messed up and do a pull request? https://github.com/faGH/WPCalendarPlugin

Comment: Wanted to check- are you using any other PhoneGap plugin in your project?

Comment: Yes, camera, geolocation and inapp browser

Answer (score 1):

Where have you stated the success callback ?
According to me the code in your js should be -

cordova.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'AddCalendarEvents', 'addCalendarEvents', inputCalendarString);

```
 function successCallback(success){
     console.log('Success');
 }

 function failureCallback(error){
     console.log('Failure');
 }
```

Also, you'll need a DispatcherCommandResult in your .cs file to return the callback.

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/windows-phone-8-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/
Have a look at this. You'll know how to use the DispatchCommandResult method to return the result to JavaScript, whether success or failure.

Comment: DispacherCommandResult fires on success of opening device calendar interface. I want to fire it on success of event creation.

Answer (score 1):

I did a workaround. Maintain localstorage flag, data with current index of events data. use resume callback to add rest of the events using custom appointment plugin that you wrote. Each time your app resumes you increment index and add events data from next index.

```
document.addEventListener('resume', this.resumeApp, false)
 resumeApp: function () {
        if (localStorage.getItem('updatecalendar') == 'false') {
            syncUpdatedCalendarWP8();
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following plugin that allows for adding of events to the native Windows Phone calendar https://github.com/faGH/fa-plugin-calendar

Comment: Indeed :) Will be sure to add that before the end of the week. For now, its a working wrap of what you have posted.