# Cordova WP8 add event to calendar

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

How can I add an event to the device's native calendar in a Windows Phone 8 app using Cordova? There does not seem to be any specific plugin to add events to the device calendar.

Comment: I believe this question has already be answered here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166510/cordova-calendar-plugin-for-windows-phone-8). Basically, a plugin already exists for what you're looking for: https://github.com/faGH/fa-plugin-calendar.

Comment: This calendar plugin does not seem to work. No event is added in the calendar after executing the sample code.'window.faCalendar.AddEvent(
    onSuccess, 
    onFailure, 
    "Event Notes",
    "Event Title",
    "Event Location",
    2015, // Event Year
    8, // Event Month
    21, // Event Day
    1.0 // Event Duration in Hours
);'